# the appropriate datatype for hex values in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I need to store Hex values into a database table, can anyone recommend the data type I need to use for the attribute?

thanks in advance

Comment: Why not just store the decimal value (much more compact to store) and convert it to whatever base you need when selecting (e.g. through a view)

Comment: What are   "Hex values", are we talking "wikipedia.zip" , `%5a` or `0xF1D0F00D`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `bytea` to store hex format. More info [can be found in the postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-binary.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a normal integer type, and if you want to convert to and from a hex string you can do this without too much trouble.

There is already a `to_hex` in postgresql. `SELECT to_hex(42)` should print `2a`. To do the reverse will require creating a new stored procedure though (taken from http://www.varlena.com/GeneralBits/104.php).

```
CREATE FUNCTION hex2dec(t text) RETURNS integer AS 
$$
 DECLARE
   r RECORD;
 BEGIN
   FOR r IN EXECUTE 'SELECT x'''||t||'''::integer AS hex' LOOP
     RETURN r.hex;
   END LOOP;
 END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT;
```

Comment: The for loop is unnecessary overhead.